# How does Google Image search can tell the dimensions of image before it loads?

Tags: javascript, image, load

When you search for images for a topic on Google, grayed out image containers load up in the dimension of images before images load.

I am trying to implement the same feature on my website, but I don't know how to get the width and height of image before they load.

Comment: Google's stored the image dimensions when they index the images in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So, I hope I understand you in loading of the image dimension on your website. Basically you can implement it in your style sheets or java script, or even with a simple mouseover in html of each image. Google uses `class="rg_ilmn"` as their style for the picture. Here is a link to a similar explanation about [Displaying Image Dimensions](http://aspforums.net/Threads/455444/Display-image-dimensions-height-and-width-on-image-mouseover-in-ASPNet/). Hope this helps.